# AES decyption with PKCS7 Padding?

Tags: apex, java, crypto, decrypt

I have encrypted some Text in Java using PKCS7. In the Crypto class it is written that PKCS5 is supported, but is there any possibility using PKCS7? Or do you know a possibility that it would work (except changing it in java, would be a high cost doing this).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is easy: It is possible. Just the normal way, PKCS5 and PKCS7 are compatible with each other.